# No images in Assets file manager and no Update Indexes option

Tags: assets, server-migration

Just got handed over ExpressionEngine from previous developer so we migrated it to our new server. There are no images in the frontend and backend admin panel. 777 permission were given to _assets, cache folders. No Update Indexes option in Addon->Modules->Assets. Assets running 1.1.3 and ExpressionEngine is on 2.3.1. When I try to upload a new image in the "empty" file manager, I get "Your upload directory isn’t writable". I suspect its temp folder and where do I set the permission for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your actual upload directory isn't writable. You can check where this is located in the file structure on the [**File Upload Preferences page of the CP**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html). Permissions should be set to 777. "_assets" probably isn't the actual upload directory but is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use underscores in the name of your Assets-folder anymore. Look at [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15323/problem-after-upgrading-assets-underscores-in-folder-names) and the comments.